# calling mprotect in kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls, kernel-module, mprotect

I have a kernel module where I need to call mprotect for the current user process. I was thinking of making a direct call to [do_mprotect_pkey](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/mprotect.c#L522) but the function is marked as `static`. If not, is there any other way like going through a system call or something?

Comment: You should not use mprotect in kernel space, but you can archive the same effects with `set_memory_(ro|rw|x|nx)` in kernel

Comment: actually, I need to use pkey_mprotect, how is it possible with `set_memory_`. Also, could you elaborate on why should I not use mprotect(for user page) in kernel space and if I want, how could I use it?

Comment: because mprotect is syscall, and you should never call syscall in kernel space.

Comment: @ruke as you can see in the [source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/mprotect.c#L670), pkey_mprotect syscall calls  do_mprotect_pkey, maybe use this one?